# Applicative functors for my own data type (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, applicative

I´m trying to understand haskell and I´m stuck with a "cannot construct the infinite type"-error

I want to implement "<*>" for my own data type, imitating the behaviour of a list.

My functioning code so far:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving Show

instance Functor (List) where
--  fmap :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    fmap f Nil = Nil
    fmap f (Cons a (b)) = Cons (f a) (fmap f b)
```

Now I´m trying to create an instance of 'Applicative List':

```
instance Applicative List where
    pure a = Cons a (Nil)
--  (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    (Cons a (b)) <*> (Cons c (d)) = Cons (fmap a (Cons c (d))) (b <*> (Cons c (d)))
    (Nil) <*> _ = Nil
    _ <*> (Nil) = Nil
```

The goal is to define '<*>' so it simulates the behaviour of a List.
Example:

```
 (fmap (*)) [5,6,3] <*> [0,2]
--> [0,10,0,12,0,6]
```

so it should create:

```
(fmap (*)) (Cons 5 (Cons 6 (Cons 3 (Nil)))) <*> (Cons 0 (Cons 2 (Nil)))
--> (Cons 0 (Cons 10 (Cons 0 (Cons 12 (Cons 0 (Cons 6 (Nil))))))))
```

but unfortunately I get a (to me) pretty unuseful error:

```
10-3.hs:14:65: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b ~ List b
      Expected type: List (List b)
        Actual type: List b
    * In the second argument of `Cons', namely `(b <*> (Cons c (d)))'
      In the expression: Cons (fmap a (Cons c (d))) (b <*> (Cons c (d)))
      In an equation for `<*>':
          (Cons a (b)) <*> (Cons c (d))
            = Cons (fmap a (Cons c (d))) (b <*> (Cons c (d)))
    * Relevant bindings include
        b :: List (a -> b) (bound at 10-3.hs:14:14)
        a :: a -> b (bound at 10-3.hs:14:11)
        (<*>) :: List (a -> b) -> List a -> List b (bound at 10-3.hs:14:18)
   |
14 |     (Cons a (b)) <*> (Cons c (d)) = Cons (fmap a (Cons c (d))) (b <*> (Cons c (d)))
   |                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I cant figure out why a List of Lists is expected (List (List b)) because the definition of my data type clearly states a normal List is required as the second parameter for Cons.

I hope someone can help me with this!

EDIT:
Thank you this solved it.
This might be off-topic now, but I was trying to copy the original syntax used for lists to solve it.
Its defined in the Prelude Package as follows:

```
instance Applicative [] where
    {-# INLINE (<*>) #-}
    fs <*> xs = [f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]
```

As I couldn´t use the list comprehension, as for me not wanting to create an actual list (shure I could just convert it later on but I dont like that idea). I translated the syntactic sugar with lambdaBot and got this:

```
fs <*> xs = concatMap (\ f -> concatMap (\ x -> [f x]) xs) fs
```

Is there a way to do it like this or is this essentialy the equivalent to doing it with an append (helper)-function?

Comment: RE your new question: you can write a `concatMap` function and use that to implement `<*>`, but `concatMap` itself is more powerful in some sense (you can't implement `concatMap` using only `<*>`). So implementing it that way is not any easier. All it does is reduce code duplication.

Comment: I recommend defining `liftA2` instead of `(<*>) = liftA2 ($)`. Lifting `a -> b -> c` to `List a -> List b -> List c` is simpler than conceptualising a datatype of functions `List (a -> b) -> ..`: `liftA2 (·) (Cons a as) bs = append (fmap (a ·) bs) (liftA2 (·) as bs)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the offending line:

```hs
  (Cons a (b)) <*> (Cons c (d)) = Cons (fmap a (Cons c (d))) (b <*> (Cons c (d)))
```

The subexpression `fmap a (Cons c (d))` has type `List b` and you are trying to `Cons` that onto `(b <*> (Cons c (d)))` which also has type `List b`. But remember that the type is `Cons :: a -> List a -> List a`. Note that the first element of `Cons` needs to be an element and the second element should be a list. So, the compiler assumes that your element type is itself `List b` and then it reports that it expects the second argument to have type `List (List b)`.

To fix this, instead of using `Cons` you should write an `append :: List a -> List a -> List a` function and use that:

```hs
  (Cons a (b)) <*> (Cons c (d)) = append (fmap a (Cons c (d))) (b <*> (Cons c (d)))
```

---

Small note about syntax: you can make the code quite a bit cleaner like this:

```
  Cons f fs <*> xs = append (fmap f xs) (fs <*> xs)
```

Tips:

- Use suggestive names like `f` for functions, and add an `s` to the end for lists of something.
- Avoid redundant pattern matching `(Cons c (d))` -> `xs`.
- Avoid redundant parentheses. In particular you *never* have to write parentheses around variables like `(b)` and `(d)`.